How to find all the AD groups that users are apart of using MS Active Directory?
I am trying to use MS Active Directory Python plug-in to manage our Active Directory domain: https://ms-active-directory.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example_find_manage_memberships.html#adding-users-to-groups
I am very beginner so below is what I've come up with to try and get it working but no luck yet. To explain the "for emails in user:" part, using 're', this is something a more experienced coworker came up with. It helps find users based off emails and find their 'CN' in the company (CN = Common Name). Having no experience with 're' I tried reusing that below 'find_users_group' to filter through the results and find only the instance of 'awsg` because the groups I'm trying to get all start with 'awsg'
For this code I have below, it prints out an empty list for 'proccessed_ad_groups' because (i believe) it's not finding anything starting with 'awsg'. If I take that out, and print the raw results, it's a messy chunk of code that has stuff like:
"CN=Managers,OU=Sales,DC=Domain,DC=Com" over and over for the thousands of users in our company.
How could I use this MS active directory plug-in to search a list of users and print out each AD group the user is in?
import re

from ms_active_directory import ADDomain, ADUser, ADGroup
domain = ADDomain('fake_name')
session = domain.create_session_as_user('my_email', 'mypassword')

ad_username_list = []
desired_group_attrs = ['memberOf']
user = ['albert.einstein@email.com', 'jon.doe@email.com']

for emails in user:
    add_user_found = session.find_user_by_name(emails)
    add_c_names =re.findall(r'\'cn\':(.*?)\,', str(add_user_found))
    processed_c_names = [i.replace('"','').replace('\'', '').strip() for i in add_c_names]
    ad_username_list.append(processed_c_names[0])


find_users_group = session.find_groups_for_users(users=ad_username_list, attributes_to_lookup=desired_group_attrs)
find_ad_groups =re.findall(r'\'awsg\':(.*?)\,', str(find_users_group))
processed_ad_groups = [i.replace('"','').replace('\'', '').strip() for i in find_ad_groups]
print(processed_ad_groups)
print(ad_username_list)


That re usage is utterly weird. Is add_user_found a dict? (What does print(type(add_user_found)) return?) If so, why aren't you accessing its elements in the normal way, via add_user_found['cn'] and such?

type(add_user_found) = <class 'ms_active_directory.core.ad_objects.ADUser'>
I am doing it that way bc CN's are usernames, but it's much easier to get emails and search emails to get the username, rather than having to find the usernames manually
